# fetchTimeEstimate not authorised - but strangely only on some iPhone's

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uber-api

I'm using the Uber Rides iOS SDK and currently only interested only in how long an uber will take to arrive, we just launch the uber app to the app if the user wants to proceed.

Strangely on some iPhones and the simulator it returns a result pretty much always (unless no cars available), but on others it says not authorised as a response.

Here is the code for the call:

```
func fetchTimeEstimates(from location: CLLocation, completion: @escaping (_ estimate: TimeEstimate?) -> Void) {

ridesClient.fetchTimeEstimates(pickupLocation: location) { (estimates, response) in
  if response.statusCode != 200 || estimates.isEmpty {
    print("UBER fetchTimeEstimates returned \(response.statusCode)")

    completion(nil)
    return
  }

  // Set default to uberX
  for i in 0...estimates.count - 1 {
    if let id = estimates[i].productID, id == UberRides.uberXProductId {
      completion(estimates[i])
      return
    }
  }

  completion(estimates[0])
}
```

}

Im using server token setup in my plist

Although it either consistently works or does not on peoples phones, It does not seem a consistent pattern, i.e. its not that the first 5 devices worked and then it stopped working after that, or type of phone or OS version.

Heres what I tried:

1. Adding a failing devices user to list of developers in the dashboard authorisation screen, no difference.
2. Requesting full api access for a 'request', nope
3. checking if a brand new phone 8 with brand new user credentials both for the phone and uber login, works fine so don't explain why we go two people in the office where its consistently refused.
4. adding the app ID in the developer console.

Any ideas why I'm getting inconsistent results, its a challenge to debug as it always works on my test phones, but annoyingly it fails consistently on the CEO's phone.

Comment: Can you please post the full error message you receive when it fails with the status code and error description?

Comment: **Status**: 401, **title:** No Authentication provided, **code:** unauthorized.

but only on some devices

Comment: If I debug RidesClient.fetchTimeEstimate and step into the apiCall function, on a working device the accessTokenString is "" but on a failing device it has a token "KA.ey.....", I would expect the opposite to be true

Comment: Can we please get some additional info like:   - what version of the SDK  you are using, is it same version of SDK on both phones where it is successful and where it fails? It is quite difficult to reproduce the problem - so we will need to narrow it down with all info you can supply.

Comment: I will be following up via email asking for more information as we cannot reproduce this problem.